# Javascript Create audio element cross browser issue

Tags: javascript, audio, cross-browser

I'm creating sound alerts that get triggered when  a message comes in. They work fine in Chrome and Firefox but do NOT work in IE 9 & Safari. here is some code :

```js
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', '/sounds/blip.wav');
audioElement.setAttribute('preload', 'auto');
audioElement.load()

    function bipTrades() {
  var tradeCheck = document.getElementById('tradeSound');
  if (tradeCheck.checked == true) {
        audioElement.play();
  }
  else {
    console.log("silent alert")
  }
};
```

so when the message comes in, the function bipTrades is triggered.

Any idea how to make this work in IE & Safari too ?

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** 
Ok seems I found why. It is a file format issue. Using mp3 it works in IE, but safari does not seem to support any audio at all. I used this script to check :

```
<script type/javascript>
        function checkAudioCompat() {
            var myAudio = document.createElement('audio');

            if (myAudio.canPlayType) {
                // CanPlayType returns maybe, probably, or an empty string.

                if ( "" != myAudio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg')) {
                    alert("mp3 supported");
                }

                if ( "" != myAudio.canPlayType('audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"')) {
                    alert("ogg supported");
                }

                if ( "" != myAudio.canPlayType('audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.5"')) {
                    alert("aac supported");
                }
            }
            else {
                alert("no audio support");
            }
        }
    </script>

<button onclick="checkAudioCompat();">
    Test for audio format type
</button>
```

Comment: Do you see a 'silent alert' message in IE/Safari? If not, the problem is probably with audio playback--not your function.

Comment: Try appending the element to the DOM somewhere before it's played.

Comment: Yes it shows silent alert (which happens when user does not want sound). Sorry Josh, don't realy understand what you mean by "appending the element to the DOM"

Comment: Safari 5.1.7 (last version for Windows) does not support `<audio>` tag. And yes, .mp3 works in IE9 but not supported in FF.